# How to find the application installed directory at runtime under websphere

Tags: java, websphere, ear

we are using WebSphere 7. WebSphere by default unpacked the installed ear application in to the
directory "installedApps" for the given node, cell of application server. I am trying to find out the directory path for this installed directory in case that the default installed directory were not used.
Does websphere provide any api that i can call from my applicaiton at runtime to find out the application installed directory?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for [`ServletContext.getRealPath(String path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29).